# Cartopy not plotting an external shapefile from ArcGis

Tags: python, gis, cartopy

I'm trying to plot a shapefile exported from ArcGis using

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io
import cartopy.feature
uf_shp = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(uf_shapefile)
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-82, -32, -45, 10])
ax.add_feature(uf_shp.geometries(), ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_geometries(uf_shp.geometries(), ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.plot()
```

and I get a blank plot. The same shapefile can be imported and visualized on QGis.

Comment: What type of geometries are they? Polygons, Lines, Points? If you add coastlines, you are getting something, right?

Comment: Without being able to *reproduce* the issue, it is very unlikely you will find a solution. Are you able to provide the shapefile?